# Cocoa/CoreFoundation : List of connected drives but not mounted & how to mount them ?

Tags: cocoa, core-foundation

Like in the Disk Utility, how can I get the list of connected drives who are not mounted. And then, how can I mount them ?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

The Disk Arbitration framework can handle various tasks such as mounting disks:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/DiscArbitrationFramework/DiskArbitration_h/

I am not really sure how Disk Utility knows about available drives but one possibility is that it monitors mount/unmount activity (using the framework above) and simply remembers the disks that have been used in the past.  For example it may automatically save the pathnames of disks in a settings file somewhere and restore that list every time it's launched.

Comment: I'm already monitoring the mounting/unmounting notification with cocoa. So it's not really helping me. :/